# How to Create JSK from certificate chain

Tags: java, keystore

I need to create a Java Key Store (JSK) file from three different certificates.
I tried keytool java command but was not able to do so.
Then I tried importing each certificate one by one . All the certificates were imported successfully and also the keytool -list command gave the output as three certificates but when I used the JSK in my code it gave error like "No key found"
So can anyone tell me how to do that.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you mean Java keystore by any chance?

Comment: What is keytool -list -v -keystore showing you?

Comment: It's showing the name of three certificates....and a comment that key stroke contains 3 entries.But when I am trying to use this I am getting this error: "caused by: Initialization error in Http Sender.process/Send HTTP Request
caused by: A security exception was thrown while trying to load the identity."

Answer (score 1):

Could you please explain/show what your code is attempting to do with your JKS (Java Key Store)?

From the steps you described above, it looks as if you have imported three certificates into a JKS, but no actual **private keys**. The error you mentioned in your code "No key found" leads me to believe that you are attempting to load and use a private key (for authentication or another purpose). The only thing you could use your JKS for above is for operations involving public keys / certificates, such as validating trust.

Comment: Thanks bob, what I am trying top achieve is that I have three certificates and I need to associate them with my server. By using these certificates I am able to create client but not able to create server. hop this help